# GZip most recent file

Tags: gzip, command-line-arguments

I know that the best way to find the most recent file is through an operation like:

```
ls -l -rt | tail -1
```

But I'm wanting to gzip this (most recent) file, because the program I'm writing will be putting a file in the current directory via a constructed command line argument in an outside interface. The user of the program shouldn't be aware of any background processes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with another pipe :

```
cat `ls -rt | tail -1` | gzip > file.gz
```

Comment: Actually, for me, that created a gzipped file that had the contents 'file', which contained the text "file.gz".

Comment: Thanks - However, that way I get the same thing but the gzippped 'file' is completely empty.

Comment: @MasonW : I had this problem but be careful, on the second launch, it will gzip the gziped file ;) try with a ../files.gz.